# Google OR Tools to force disjunctions/prevent certain locations from being connected?

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am successfully recreating the [pickup and delivery vehicle routing problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/pickup_delivery) but I want to add an extra constraint which I cannot find anywhere how to implement it: I want my vehicles to always return to depot after a pickup-delivery. How can I enforce this constraint? It seems that if I add a disjunction then the solver might end up not delivering to a specific delivery location.

Comment: Just modify the distance matrix such that the only way out of a delivery is to the depot. Or add a dimension with capacity 1, increased by one at the delivery.

Comment: @LaurentPerron Thanks for the prompt reply. Could you please provide an example in both cases so as to understand exactly what you mean and accept the solution in a separate answer?

Comment: @LaurentPerron I think the answer is what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
def counter_callback(from_index):
    """Returns 1 for any locations except depot."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to user NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    return 1 if (from_node != 0) else 0;

counter_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(counter_callback)

routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
    counter_callback_index,
    0,  # null slack
    [4,5,4,6],  # maximum locations per vehicle
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    'Counter')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define vehicle depots (start and/or end) directly when initializing:

```
# Create the routing index manager.
self.manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(locations), len(vehicles), start_depots, end_depots)
self.routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(self.manager)
```

start_depots and end_depots are both lists, the size of vehicles. Same depots can be in both lists